# Running subquery for each row

Tags: postgresql

I got these two queries, but cant get my head around how to combine them:

```
SELECT a.trainid, a.time AS departuretime, b.time AS arrivaltime, (b.timestamp-a.timestamp) AS journeytime, a.estimate as estimateA, b.estimate as estimateB
FROM public.snapshot AS a 
INNER JOIN public.snapshot AS b ON a.trainid=b.trainid
WHERE a.location = '49K' AND NOT a.location=b.location AND (b.timestamp-a.timestamp) BETWEEN 10 AND 5000
```

and

```
SELECT a.location, ROUND(AVG(b.timestamp-a.timestamp)) AS avgjourneytime, ROUND(AVG(a.estimate)) as avgestimateA, ROUND(AVG(b.estimate)) as avgestimateB, COUNT(*) as records
FROM public.snapshot AS a INNER JOIN public.snapshot AS b ON a.trainid=b.trainid
WHERE (b.timestamp-a.timestamp) BETWEEN 180 AND 5000 AND ((#a.timestamp from query above#)%86400-a.timestamp%86400) BETWEEN -900 AND 900 AND a.location = '49K'
GROUP BY a.location
```

So basically I want as output

```
a.trainid, departuretime, arrivaltime, journeytime, estimateA, estimateB, avgjourneytime, avgestimateA, avgestimateB, records
```

Example data:

```
a.trainid, departuretime, arrivaltime, journeytime, estimateA, estimateB, avgjourneytime, avgestimateA, avgestimateB, records
54, 14:00, 14:05, 300, 600, 400, 320, 620, 420, 3
57, 15:00, 15:10, 600, 800, 400, 860, 420, 420, 4
```

So for all the averages, I only want the records considered which are were on a previous day +/- 15 minutes of the departure time of that row, so for the first row I only want the average of trains that departed between 13:45 and 14:15, and for the second row the average of all trains between 14:45 and 15:15. Records says how many records were considered for the average.
Also, is there a way to do differentiate between weekdays, Saturdays and Sundays?

The average values are within +/- 15 minutes on a previous day, the timestamp values are seconds since 01/01/1970 - UTC, so modulo 86400 is one day.

Using Postgres.

Comment: Show us what you have attempted so far. All you have done so far is ask us to write something for you

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
select q1.*,q2.* from
(
    SELECT a.trainid as trainid, a.time AS departuretime, b.time AS arrivaltime, (b.timestamp-a.timestamp) AS journeytime, a.estimate as estimateA, b.estimate as estimateB
    FROM public.snapshot AS a 
    INNER JOIN public.snapshot AS b ON a.trainid=b.trainid
    WHERE a.location = '49K' AND NOT a.location=b.location AND (b.timestamp-a.timestamp) BETWEEN 10 AND 5000
)q1,
(
    SELECT a.trainid as trainid,a.location, ROUND(AVG(b.timestamp-a.timestamp)) AS avgjourneytime, ROUND(AVG(a.estimate)) as avgestimateA, ROUND(AVG(b.estimate)) as avgestimateB, COUNT(*) as records
    FROM public.snapshot AS a INNER JOIN public.snapshot AS b ON a.trainid=b.trainid
    WHERE (b.timestamp-a.timestamp) BETWEEN 180 AND 5000 AND ((#a.timestamp from query above#)%86400-a.timestamp%86400) BETWEEN -900 AND 900 AND a.location = '49K'
    GROUP BY a.location
)q2 
where q1.trainid=q2.trainid;
```